# Arduino Timer 1 Library manipulate Timer value

Tags: arduino-uno, library, timers

I'm using Timer1 library for generation of pulse.
But in my code, at some places i need to change the timer values.
Can anyone suggest the ways to do it.

In below code in place of 370000, I need to change the value after getting some inputs in conditional loops.
Ex. if (x==1) Timer value should be 370000 else 185000.

```
#include <TimerOne.h>

int count = 0;
int LED = 13;

void setup() {
 pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
 Timer1.initialize(370000);
 Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
 Serial.print("Count Value: ");
 Serial.println(count++);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you look into TimerOne.h, which is the header file for the TimerOne library, you can see [at line 55](https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/TimerOne/blob/ce0fa0b7965f189925d8b7dbba49d562f7c0a4b3/TimerOne.h#L55) the method

```
void setPeriod(unsigned long microseconds)
```

which can be used to set the period of the timer at any time in your program. The method `TimerOne.initialize()` also calls this method to set the timer period.

Answer (score -1):

Just use a variable...

```
unsigned long val = 0;

void setup(){
  if(something){
    val = 370000;
  } 
  else {
    val = 185000;
  }
  Timer1.initialize(val);
}
```

Comment: Calling the `initialize` method multiple times feels wrong. In some libraries this can have some weird side effects. In the case of Timer1 if you call `detachInterrupt` and then change the period using `initialize`, instead of `setPeriod`, the interrupts will start again, and you ISR will get called. Though I admit that's a bit of an edge case.

Comment: Who said to call it multiple times?  It's only called once in setup.  Is there more to this than was in the question?  I thought we were coming up with a way to alter the 370000 number.  Question should be more specific.  If this answer is a downvote for answering exactly what the question said then I'm downvoting the question for being vague.

Comment: @Delta_G - You can call the `initialize` function twice per minute with different values if you like. I've built a clock that does just that, and has been running for over a year with no issues. https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/68627/37523 +1 for your answer.

Comment: I still say the question didn't ask to do it over and over.  The question just asked how to do it once in setup.

Comment: @Delta_G - The question is not the greatest, but it does say `...at some places i need to change the timer values`. I still like your answer :)

Comment: While it does say that, I figured that was a language issue as the code posted shows nothing in loop and only shows the one Timer1 function being called.  If that's not the code the OP needed help with then why is that the code that was posted?

Comment: @Delta_G that's right I didn't post the full code here. Let me clarify. I'm blinking LED/Bulbs with arduino. On time of that will be 370ms and same off time. After current/load sensing, if load is in range, I need to start timer with 370000. If not, timer should count 185000. So here is my question, that once I initialize timer to 370000 in setup, is it possible to change that value later in code. Because i badly need to change the timer value. Hope this clarify the things and doesn't sound stupid enough to down vote the question.

Comment: @Delta_G Also let me add something to question that, once I start blinking LED/Bulbs with timer say 370ms. After starting timer, in ON timer I'm checking load/current by polling. If load not appropriate, I've to change value from 370000 to 185000 while timer is still going on with 370000.

Comment: This would all be simpler without the timer library if that's all you need to do.  Just use millis for the timing.